# How can send mail via Gmail to more than 500 contacts of my friends? ( I don't want to set me as spammer)

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

Many of my friends use Gmail. When I want to send them attractive emails, I have a group named everyone that I use it.

After that I send email to my friends, and remind them to check their mailboxes, they tell me, not delivered! But when I tell them

> please check your Spam folder

They report that they've received it. Is there any way to tell Gmail to send, x mails every y minutes?

Comment: i find software named sendmail , i have a free and strong one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: You cannot send more than 500 emails in a day from a single Gmail account.

[Google will temporarily disable your account if you send messages to more than 500 recipients or if you send a large number of undeliverable messages.](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839&topic=1669057&ctx=topic)

[If you access Gmail via POP or IMAP clients (like Microsoft Outlook), you can send an email message to a maximum of 100 people at a time. Cross the limit and your account will be disabled for a day with the error “550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded.](http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-for-sending-mass-emails/11278/)

Gmail has [these guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) for sending bulk emails. You may ask your friends to add you email address to their Contacts list to avoid emails you send from landing in their Spam folder

Comment: did you know any mail sender application with good merge tools? and feature like delay in sending emails?

Comment: check if the Merge Tags (http://mailchimp.com/features/merge-tags/) and Time Warp (http://mailchimp.com/features/time-warp/) features of MailChimp suit your needs